# How to display session data on view template in Laravel 5

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I'm trying to display session data on a view template in Laravel 5.  However it doesn't seem to show anything.

Here is the code i'm using to set the session:

```
Session::set('bookingConfirmed', BookingDates::where('id', Session::get('bookingFormData.slot.id'))->first());
```

Here is the code i'm using to display:

```
{{ Session::get('bookingConfirmed->time') }}
```

Comment: how to display in class html? ejm. `class="app-{{ Session::get('btn') }}"` No work :(

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm guessing it's because you've got the attribute of the object within the string that identifies the key of the object you want to get. I.e. move `->time` as so:

```
{{ Session::get('bookingConfirmed')->time }}
```

You may also want to check it exists firstly too:

```
@if(Session::has('bookingConfirmed'))
    {{ Session::get('bookingConfirmed')->time }}
@endif
```

Comment: What is time here and why?

Comment: @151291 It is irrelevant to the question/answer. It appears to be an attribute on the value the user is retrieving from the session, most likely an eloquent object as there's an eloquent call when they're setting the value in the session. See the question.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to try first getting the object and then get the fields of it like this

```
{{ Session::get('bookingConfirmed')->time }}
```