# How to store the selected quantities in the session and show this info in next page?

Tags: php, laravel

I have basketball match details page "single.blade.php" and a page to purchase a ticket "payment.blade.php". In the match details page, the user can select through a select option the type of tickets and how many of each one they want.

Im in doubt about how to get the quantity of each ticket selected by the user in the match details page, store that info in the session  and send that information to the payment page to be possible to show the selected ticket types and quantities in the next page (payment page).

**Code structure that I have for this question:**

I have a FrontController and it has the single() method to show the match details page:

```
public function single($id){
    $match = Match::where('id', $id)->first();
    $tickets = Ticket::where('match_id', $match_id->id)->get();
    return view('matchs.show')->with('match',$match)->with('match', $match)->with('tickets', $tickets);
}
```

Then in the match details page I have the types of tickets listed and for each one there is a select menu so the user can select how many tickets want for each one:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($tickets as $ticket)
        <li>
            <span>{{$ticket->title}}</span> 
            <form method="post" action="{{route('matchs.payment', ['id' => $match->id, 'slug' => $match->slug])}}">

                <select name={{ $ticket->title }}>
                    <option selected>0</option>
                     <option value="1">1</option>
                     <option value="2">2</option>
                     <option value="3">3</option>
                     <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
            </form>
            <span>X {{$ticket->showPrice()}}</span>
        </li>
    @endforeach
    <li>
        <span>TOTAL</span>
        <span>0.00€</span>
    </li>
    <input type="submit" value="Go To Payment Page"/>
    </form>
</ul>
```

After user select the quantities and click "Next" he should go to the payment page and the selected types and quatities in the previous page should be presented in this payment page. So, I have a PaymentController and I created a storeQuantity() method. Do you know how to properly store in this method the selected types and quantities in the session and then how to show this info in the payment page?

```
class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    public function storeQuantity(Request $request){
        //dd($request->all());
        return view('matchs.payment');
    }
}
```

route:

```
Route::post('/match/{id}/{slug?}/payment', [
    'uses' => 'PaymentController@storeQuantity',
    'as'   =>'matchs.payment'
]);
```

The `dd($request->all());` shows:

```
array:2 [▼
  "center_bench" => "1"
  "left_bench"   => "1"
]
```

Note: I also dont know if its really necessary sessions, maybe the next button can have a post route and pass the necessary info (selected tickets and quantities) to the next page (payment page) but Im not understanding how the process is.

Comment: You could just use sesssion()->put('ticket', SELECTED_NUMBER);
Which you can retrive like session()->get('ticket'). i think you can use these helpers in view as well.

Comment: Thanks, but the select menu name is dynamic, "name={{ $ticket->title }}", so how to get the ticket title and the quantity selected and store store that in the session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will work for you...

> name={{ Session::put($ticket->title, SELECTED_NUMBER)}}

you can visit [display session data on view template in laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30595350/how-to-display-session-data-on-view-template-in-laravel-5)

Comment: Thanks, but so that info is stored in the session in the conference details page in the name attribute and not in the storeQuantity() method of the PaymentController? And then how to redirect to the payment page?

Comment: i think session flash data helps you. Sometimes you may wish to store items in the session only for the next request. You may do so using the flash method. visit [https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session#flash-data] or [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37485527/how-to-pass-data-through-a-redirect-to-a-view-in-laravel] i hope it will work for you...

Comment: But how to store the selected quantity for each ticket type (that is dynamic)?

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of functionality which is similar to a cart system in a ecommerce website we use the javascript `local storage`
You can do these step
When the use will select an option then do a `onchange()` function which will just store the value of the selected item in the javascript local storage but before storing it will check if any value of same `key` is present or not ( this will make it dynamic that is if the use want to change the selected value ) 
Then when the submit button will clicked take the value from the javascript localstorage and either put it in a session ( use flash session) or just send it in a post request

Comment: Thanks, but why is necessary local storage? It doesnt work without local storage and when the "next" button is clicked send a post request with the information of selected quantites of each ticket type?

Comment: You can use cookies also but the  expiring time should be less and logical . But the javascript local storage are good and easy option . Every browser provide some storage which you can use with javascript